# Rails taking longer than expected to load page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I came across these stats in rails console

**Completed 200 OK in 879ms (Views: 57.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)**

As you can see views load time and activerecord times take ~60ms. But instead the load time was 879ms. Where can the other 800ms be attributed to? (sometimes its as much as 2000ms)

full trace

```
Started GET "/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-17 02:10:13 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."firstname" = 'Andr' AND "users"."id" != 2 AND "users"."is_artist" = 't') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."cname" = 'chic' AND "users"."id" != 2 AND "users"."is_artist" = 't') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'pk00218@surrey.ac.uk' AND "users"."id" != 2 AND "users"."is_artist" = 't') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."spotify_name" = 'nickelback' AND "users"."id" != 2 AND "users"."is_artist" = 't') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."soundcloud_link" = 'nickelback' AND "users"."id" != 2 AND "users"."is_artist" = 't') LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_search_bar.html.erb (0.3ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_artist" = $1  [["is_artist", "t"]]
  Tagging Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."user_id" IN (1, 2)
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
  Rendered shared/_artist_tile.html.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_artist_tile.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_artist_tile.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (17.6ms)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "collective_requests" WHERE "collective_requests"."receiver_id" = $1 AND "collective_requests"."accepted" IS NULL  [["receiver_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "collective_requests" WHERE "collective_requests"."receiver_id" = $1 AND "collective_requests"."accepted" IS NULL  [["receiver_id", 2]]
  Rendered layouts/_navlinks.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 879ms (Views: 57.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

Rails version is **4.2.6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails cannot measure everything your code does (eg. connecting to Redis, complex logic in a method). You need a APM tool like New Relic to figure out which part of your code is slow.

Here is a sample trace by each method and time taken:

[image: Rails APM NewRelic]

Ref - https://blog.newrelic.com/2012/06/21/adventures-in-performance-tuning/